# Example of a ring of infinite uniform dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to find an example of a ring of infinite uniform dimension. We say that a ring has uniform dimension $n$ if there exists $n$ non-zero ideals $I_{i}$ of $R$ such that

$$ \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} I_{i},$$

and every direct sum of ideals of $R$ has at most $n$ summands. Otherwise, we say that the ring has infinite uniform dimension.

Any help?

Comment: This is a good question for the Database of ring theory. Here are [over 20 examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?L=85r) of rings with infinite uniform dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a commutative example, then any infinite product of fields will do.

If you need a domain, it’s well-known that a domain $R$ is right Ore iff $R_R$ has finite uniform dimension.

Such rings are easy to construct as skew polynomial rings.